# Functions with Expansion Protection when working with Section Headings

Tags: sectioning, protected-macro

I would like to understand why defining new section heading would require function to have protection from expansion.

Comment: as has already been explained protection makes things safe in a write, and section headings get written to the toc file for table of contents, "fragile commands in moving arguments" should be in any basic latex tutorial.

Comment: Can you direct me on the basic latex tutorial.  I would be glad to see an example for section heading where expansion protection would be required.  Because I have not seen much in terms of example code.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22fragile+command+in+moving+argument%22

Comment: Basically I get that stuff in `\section` is written into table of contents, which breaks things.  Hardly anything that one can learn from.  Then there is the `moving in fragile` ridiculous speech.

Comment: Could there be an answer showing how putting something using a function in a section header fails if one does not use `\cs_new_protected:Nn`.

Comment: it is not "ridiculous speech" they are specific terms defined in the latex book. A "fragile command" is one that is not protected and a "moving argument" is an argument where such commands fail. If you use a fragile command in a moving argument then expansion goes wrong and you get weird internal (more or less spurious) error messages as tex can't really recover in any clean way.

Comment: They could have called them `Defective Arguments`.

Comment: It seems that just being rude about latex design is a current pastime amongst a group of users (or the same user with multiple accounts?) . Using protection (with classic tex) doubles the number of command names used and on a 640K PC running emtex that was not an option. Even adding 100 extra commands would have gone over the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be the most Frequent of frequently asked question as almost all latex commands were fragile and failed by default in headings, but these days most are robust by default (as more memory allows that). So an example showing a command with a `*` form defined the classical way, so it is fragile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\foo{\@ifstar{star}{not star}}
%\protected\def\foo{\@ifstar{star}{not star}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

1 \foo

2 \foo*

\section{aaa \foo*  bbb}
xxx

\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.16 \section{aaa \foo*  bbb}
                             
?
```

as `\@ifstar` lookahead fails in the `\write` needed for the table of contents, but if you switch the definition to `\protected\def` then the `\write` is safe and the `aux` file has

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}aaa \foo * bbb}{1}{}\pro
tected@file@percent }
```

where `\foo`  did not expand at all, but just wrote as itself.

Comment: Does this mean that even in the `L3 Layer`, the same breakage problem exists ?  Would you discard the `Expansion Protection` if you could ? That is, is the current use of `Expansion Protection` still intended as a solution to breakage problems, or would one actually need it as a useful feature in the Latex Language ?

Comment: @Fluffy yes basically when defining expl3 functions they should always be _expandable_ (no internal assignments and no `x` arguments)  or _protected_ (declared with one of the `_protected_` declarations that uses `\protected\def` then all functions are basically safe to use in any argument. But if you use the non protected definitions then you will hit the above issue.

Comment: The conclusion is then that `\cs_new_protected:Nn` is there to solve specific problems rather than being a language feature.

Comment: @Fluffy that isn't the conclusion I would make.

Comment: `\cs_new_protected_` is there to expose the e-tex primitive `\protected\def` feature. expl3 in general is written in e-tex and is designed to make all its features available, but with a more consistent syntax. @Fluffy

Comment: It is there to stop expansion when needed but also to stop things from breaking in certain instances.